# Flexslider flickers while loading

Tags: slider, flexslider, jquery-ui-slider

Flexslider is not working fine in my sites, they always flicker on load.
http://bgk.copperspoke.ca/
I used all CSS hacks.

Feel free to suggest other sliders, I am open to try new
Just want smooth sliding of images